# Deserialize Json Response With Base Class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I do not have control over the json response, but the response I'm given has a list of objects that are the same, but are names differ with each object. They really are the same object, but I can't figure out how to deserialize it bc of the differing names. 
Ex:

```
{   
"Data": { 
       "OBJ_1": {
           "Id": "4321",
           "Url": "/test/url/1"
       },
       "OBJ_2": {
           "Id": "749869",
           "Url": "/test/ur1/1"
       }
    } 
}
```

I do not know the number of objects or their names so I cannot correctly add the model.

Comment: You should be fine with a `public class SomeName { public Dictionary<string, AnotherName> Data { get; set; } }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [JObject.Parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm) to get the object by JSON key name.

so if there are many objects and different name you get the property by key name.

Here is a sample get `ID` from the object.

```
string jsonData = @"{   
    'Data': { 
        'OBJ_1': {
            'Id': '4321',
            'Url': '/test/url/1'
        },
        'OBJ_2': {
            'Id': '749869',
            'Url': '/test/ur1/1'
        }
    } 
}";

var o = JObject.Parse(jsonData);

foreach (var item in o["Data"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.First.Value<string>("Id"));
}
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qq1ZFQ)

**Result**

```
4321
749869
```